# How to get the first child node of the root element in xml using DOM parser?

Tags: java, xml, spring-mvc

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<catalog>
  <book id="bk101">
    <author>Gambardella</author>
    <title>Horrro story</title>
    <genre>Computer</genre>
    <price>44.95</price>
    <publish_date>2000-10-01</publish_date>
  </book>

  <book id="bk102">
    <author>Ralls, Kim</author>
    <title>Midnight Rain</title>
    <genre>Fantasy</genre>
    <price>5.95</price>
    <publish_date>2000-12-16</publish_date>
  </book>
</catalog>
```

In this I used the following code to get the root element "catalog":

```
Node childNode = document.getFirstChild();  
System.out.println("child node  "+childNode.getNodeName());
```

I want to print root elements first child element (i.e. "book"). How to get the value of "book"?

Comment: Looks to me like you're programming in a specific language, using specific libraries.  You should add that to both the tags and the question itself, to help the right people find you.  :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
Node childNode = document.getDocumentElement().getFirstChild(); // first book element
```

or

```
NodeList childNodes = document.getDocumentElement().getChildNodes(); // all book elements
```

Comment: I tried it , its printing something like this :  [#text: 
   ]

Comment: What element or attribute of book are you trying to read? You should call [`getTextContent()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Node.html#getTextContent()) for retrieving the text content of a `Node`.

Comment: I just want to retrieve "book". How to do it ?

Comment: Use `getTextContent()`.

Comment: I got it. It is printing #text because of the white space before the node. I have to check whether it is a node or not , to get the original node.   
 NodeList nodl=document.getDocumentElement().getChildNodes();
 for (int i = 0;i < nodl.getLength(); i++) {
 Node node = nodl.item(i);                                                                 if (node.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
ele=node.getNodeName();
        System.out.println("node name: " + node.getNodeName());
                     break;
                 }
             }